# Adding new Op in Tensorflow: shape functions

Tags: tensorflow

I'm trying to add a new Op (using this how-to: https://www.tensorflow.org/how_tos/adding_an_op/). I have no problem with simple Op like in example, but I need to add more complex Op. It should have 2 inputs, and output that has same shape as matrix multiplication of inputs. 
How can I write shape function for this case?
How can I allocate output with appropriate shape?
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Have partial answer to the question.
I still don't know how to write shape function, but I wrote checks like this:

```
const Tensor& input1 = context->input(0);
const Tensor& input2 = context->input(1);
TensorShape sh1 = input1.shape();
TensorShape sh2 = input2.shape();
OP_REQUIRES(context, sh1.dim_size(1)==sh2.dim_size(0),
 errors::InvalidArgument("Can't multiplicate!"));
```

Allocating:

```
sh1.RemoveDim(1);
sh2.RemoveDim(0);
sh1.AppendShape(sh2);
OP_REQUIRES_OK(context, context->allocate_output(0, sh1, &output_tensor));
```

But seems like I'm reinventing a bicycle. Is it any easier way to do it?